# Как избежать дублирования кода при обработке исключения

Tags: c#

У меня есть три метода, которые возвращают массив строк и  выбрасывают одно и тоже исключение если доступ к этим строкам запрещен. У двух методов сигнатуры одинаковые, но у третьго она отличается. Можно ли как то выполнить проверку на выброс исключения без дублирования кода? Или его тут по факту нет?

```
{
    private string[] GetInnerEntries1(string path) {...};
    private string[] GetInnerEntries2(string path){...};
    private string[] GetRootEntries(){...};

    private delegate string[] GetInner(string path)

    private string[] TryGetInnerEntries1(string path, GetInner getInner)
    {
        string[] result=null;
        try
        {
            result= getInner(path);
        }
        catch(AccessException)
        {

        }
        return result;
    }

    private string[] TryGetInnerEntries()
    {
        string[] result = null;
        try
        {
            result = GetRootEntries();
        }
        catch (AccessException)
        {

        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Думала сделать через делегаты, но у методов разные сигнатуры, поэтому дублирование опять возникает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите внимательней на ваши методы, в чем отличие? Только по сути в `string path, GetInner getInner`. Так почему бы не сделать один метод?

К примеру, самое простое - это сделать что то вроде этого:

```
private string[] TryGetInnerEntries(string path = null, GetInner getInner = null)
{
    string[] result = null;
    try
    {
        result = path == null ? GetRootEntries() : getInner(path);
    }
    catch (AccessException)
    {

    }
    return result;
}
```

Ну а вообще, как по мне - лучше объединить `GetRootEntries()` и `getInner(path)`, но я не знаю их логику...